# Hibernate JOIN ON generates invalid query

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I need to list all `Product` records whether or not they have a corresponding `ForeignProductInfo`. `Product` has no reference to `ForeignProductInfo`.

I'm using this JPA query:

```
@Query("select distinct fpi from Product pp "
        + "left join fetch ForeignProductInfo fpi on fpi.partner.id = :partnerId "
        + "left join fetch fpi.product p ") 
public List<ForeignProductInfo> loadAllForPartner(@Param("partnerId") Long partnerId);
```

This works until I add the second join (to avoid n+1 selects when accessing `ForeignProductInfo.product`). Then it generates this SQL:

```
SELECT 
    foreignpro1_.id AS id1_7_0_,
    product2_.id AS id1_12_1_,
    productsub3_.id AS id1_18_2_,
    productgro4_.id AS id1_14_3_,
    foreignpro1_.code AS code2_7_0_,
    foreignpro1_.name AS name3_7_0_,
    foreignpro1_.partner_id AS partner_4_7_0_,
    foreignpro1_.product_id AS product_5_7_0_,
    product2_.a AS a2_12_1_,
    product2_.b AS b3_12_1_,
    product2_.comment AS comment4_12_1_,
    product2_.conversionMethod AS conversi5_12_1_,
    product2_.diaMax AS diaMax6_12_1_,
    product2_.diaMin AS diaMin7_12_1_,
    product2_.len AS len8_12_1_,
    product2_.mu AS mu9_12_1_,
    product2_.name AS name10_12_1_,
    product2_.nameLang1 AS nameLan11_12_1_,
    product2_.nameLang2 AS nameLan12_12_1_,
    product2_.productSubGroup_id AS product15_12_1_,
    product2_.surfaceMax AS surface13_12_1_,
    product2_.surfaceMin AS surface14_12_1_,
    productsub3_.name AS name2_18_2_,
    productsub3_.productGroup_id AS productG3_18_2_,
    productgro4_.name AS name2_14_3_,
    productgro4_.seq AS seq3_14_3_
FROM
    Product product0_
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
    ForeignProductInfo foreignpro1_ ON (foreignpro1_.partner_id = 3);
```

As you can see, the second JOIN is missing and causes an exception:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'product2_.id' in 'field list'
```

EDIT: `ForeignProductInfo` has zero or one record for the combination of each `Product` and `Partner`.

```
@Entity
public class ForeignProductInfo {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    private Partner partner;

    @ManyToOne
    private Product product;

    @Column(length=50)
    @Size(max=50)
    private String code;

    @Column(length=200)
    @Size(max=200)
    private String name;
    ...
}
```

Comment: If I'm getting this right, in your schema `ForeignProductInfo.product` points to the original `Product`, right?

Comment: If so, it seems your explicit declaration `on fpi.partner.id = :partnerId` overrides any `on` condition that would be generated, as we can see.  It only generated a query with your condition. My guess is you don't need the second join, just use `on fpi.partner.id = :partnerId and fpi.product = pp`, or `on fpi.partner.id = :partnerId and fpi.product.id = pp.id` if you need to be more verbose.

Comment: Yes, it points to the original `Product`, which also has some relations that would need to be fetched. Unfortunately, your suggested solution fails during query validation: `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: query specified join fetching, but the owner of the fetched association was not present in the select list`

Comment: Well, my last idea on this is to remove the second join and the `on` clause to use an implicit one, and use a where clause with `fpi.partner.id = :partnerId or fpi.partner is null`

Comment: Actually the null check should be on whatever the `ForeignProductInfo`'s primary key is,

Comment: query makes little sense since it introduces "pp" as candidate yet makes no use of that. Easier just to have fpi as the candidate if not using it.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm too stupid to figure this out. I have added the declaration of `ForeignProductInfo` at the end of my question. If you can tell me how to get a list of `ForeignProductInfo` records with their `product` fields set to the record that belongs to the specified partner ID (or set to `NULL` if such a record does not exist), I will appreciate it. (The important thing is to have one record for *every* product.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't figure this out in 3 days. This is the simplest thing in SQL but seems impossible to achieve in JPA. Also tried the criteria API, but conditional fetching is not possible, only conditional joining.

I ended up walking a list of `Product`'s and loading their `ForeignProductInfo` one by one. :( Then ditched JPA and used plain SQL for this.