# How to fetch an @ElementCollection map's related tables

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, criteria-api

This is a simple Product entity that refers to a subgroup:

```
public class Product implements Comparable<Product> {
    ...    
    @ManyToOne(optional=false, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @NotNull
    private ProductSubGroup productSubGroup;
    ...
}
```

I have a map containing `Product`'s in another entity:

```
public class FinishedProduct {
    ...
    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne
    private Product product;

    @ElementCollection(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapKeyJoinColumn
    @Column(name="amount")
    @Sort(type=SortType.NATURAL)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    private SortedMap<Product, Double> byproducts = new TreeMap<>();   
    ...
}
```

I can load the map with this code:

```
Root<FinishedProduct> root = q.from(FinishedProduct.class);
root.fetch("product", JoinType.LEFT);
root.fetch("byproducts", JoinType.LEFT);
```

This works, but I need the `productSubGroup` of the byproducts stored in the map without generating n+1 selects. How can I fetch them? Just adding the fetch to the end results in an exception:

```
root.fetch("byproducts", JoinType.LEFT).fetch("productSubGroup", JoinType.LEFT);

org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: 
Collection of values [null] cannot be source of a fetch
```

Also tried to fool around with `MapJoin`, same exception:

```
MapJoin<FinishedProduct,Product,Double> map = root.joinMap("byproducts", JoinType.LEFT);
map.fetch("productSubGroup", JoinType.LEFT);
```

I guess I somehow need to refer to the map key, but no idea how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are a bit complex mappings that you have here and I am not sure if there is an easier way to accomplish this. Hopefully somebody will provide a better answer, but as an alternative there is always the ability to pre-load into the persistence context all the entity instances that you know will be fetched with n+1 selects.

So, before firing your query, just load all `ProductSubGroup`s which are expected to be fetched:

```
select p.productSubGroup from Product p
where p in (select index(byproducts) from FinishedProduct)
```

Of course, repeat any other additional restrictions on `FinishedProduct` in the subquery which you have in your original query to avoid loading `ProductSubGroup`s which you don't need.

As even better alternative (in my opinion), you may want to consider defining [`@BatchSize`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35039402/4754790) for `Product.productSubGroup` association. That way `ProductSubGroup`s would be loaded in batches instead of one by one.

Comment: Both are valuable suggestions, although I couldn't make `@BatchSize` work in this Spring Boot/Data/JPA/Hibernate mess for some reason. But the other worked, just had to add `@Transactional` to the calling controller method.

Comment: I was hoping to apply your solution to my other problem at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40419986/hibernate-join-on-generates-invalid-query but that's unfortunately different, because caching works by ID and a three-way join queries by two other IDs, I guess.

Comment: Sometimes I think there is a person in the Hibernate team whose sole job is to find real-life usage scenarios and make them impossible. :)

Comment: Like in any framework, there are some missing features that could be useful (like outer joins with non-associated entities which may be related to your other question), and some things that may seem unintuitive at first glance. It takes time to get used to ORM concepts.